# im having a problem with this everytime i run my code.. heres my code

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

```
class DB
    {
      private  MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port:3306;username=root;password=;database=users_db");
        public void openConnection()
        {
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
        }
        public void closeConnection()
        {
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        public MySqlConnection getConnection()
        {
            return getConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

it succesfully run but after the login process.. theres an exception

- System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported.
  Parameter name: port:3306;username'

Comment: Is it a typo? _return getConnection()_ inside the getConnection method?

Comment: [Please consider adding a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with exact lines where error occur.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in the ":" in the "port" parameter, you must specify the parameter by "=" like in this example:

```
"Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"
```

Do you have tons off examples in this [page](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/),

Comment: @Abdulrahmann . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  You should accept this answer and ask a *new* question if you have further, different issues.

Answer (score -2):

now i am getting this problem in

```
public MySqlConnection getConnection()
        {
            return getConnection();
        }
```

System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'

Comment: You should update this in you question and post as a answer

Comment: `public MySqlConnection GetConnection() => connection;` And stop naming methods from lowercase.